# An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, rss

actually i already did some windows phone 8 application with xml parsing like parsing news rss feeds and were working fine., but i have problem with my latest project.,

i have one political news rss feed (http://ibnlive.in.com//ibnrss//rss//india//india.xml) and trying to parse it and show it in list.,

but i cant parse it., i hope my code is correct

Here is my code c#

```
namespace indianPolitics
{
public partial class news1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ProgressIndicator _progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    public news1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += news1_Loaded;
    }
    void news1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient _client = new WebClient();
        _client.DownloadStringCompleted += _client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        _client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ibnlive.in.com//ibnrss//rss//india//india.xml", UriKind.Absolute));

        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = _progressIndicator;
        _progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
        _progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    }
    private void _client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Error Message"+e.Error.Message);
            });
         }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Result Before Parse:"+e.Result);
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                var all = xmlDoc.Descendants("channel");
                List<News1> _singleRsses = new List<News1>();
                foreach (var item in all)
                {
                    var itemVedio = item.Descendants("item");
                    foreach (var xElement in itemVedio)
                    {
                        string _title = xElement.Element("title").Value;
                        string _description = xElement.Element("description").Value;
                        string pubDate = xElement.Element("pubDate").Value;
                        string link = xElement.Element("link").Value;

                        News1 _singleRss = new News1
                        {
                            Title = _title,
                            Description = _description,
                            PubDate = pubDate,
                            Link = link
                        };
                        _singleRsses.Add(_singleRss);
                    }
                }
                singleListbox.DataContext = _singleRsses;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception: "+exp);
                _progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
                _progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                _progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
                _progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private void News1Grid_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class News1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PubDate { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

}

and my XAML code

```
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NewsDateTemplate">
                <Grid Tag="{Binding Link}" x:Name="News1Grid" Tap="News1Grid_Tap"  Width="420" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PubDate}" Foreground="LightGoldenrodYellow" FontSize="18"/>
                    <Border Background="#FFD69F0B" Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Width="420" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                       <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="1" Grid.Row="3" Opacity=".5"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Name="ministerHeader" Text="Ministers" FontSize="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Times New Roman" ></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <ListBox Name="singleListbox" Margin="0,85,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewsDateTemplate}">

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Note: if i parse with other xml feeds like this (http://www.skysports.com//rss//0,20514,11827,00.xml) means

it parse that xml fine and show data in list box.,

i have also print that result from

```
  private void _client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
```

event handler with

```
    MessageBox.Show("Result Before Parse:"+e.Result);
```

and it shows " empty " message box.,

And also in

```
     catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception: "+exp);
             }
```

it shows error like this:

```
        "Exception: Root Element Missing"
```

Please some one give me correct solution for that ., i have most couple of weeks getting struggle with that .,

thanks in advance.,

Comment: Why have you got double forward slashes in your URL?

Comment: will you share your xml string ???

Comment: Use this:-_client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://ibnlive.in.com//ibnrss//rss//india//india.xml", UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: hi pradeep., if i tried with calling uri like u said _client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"ibnlive.in.com//ibnrss//rss//india//india.xml", UriKind.Absolute)); means., it shows another error like., " An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.ni.dll "..

Comment: and john asked that why this url has double forward slash., actually that url is given from that domain(ibnlive.com).,

Comment: and also i have given another url from skysports.com (http://www.skysports.com//rss//0,20514,11827,00.xml) ., it also has double forward slash., but when i used this URL it was working fine

Comment: please try to test my code with both URLs and give me what the exact problem is., thank you for spending time guys.,